# Get content of loaded SVG file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have made function that will load to specific div svg file from url:

```
function load_vector(divId, vector_url) {
    var div = $(divId);

    div.load(vector_url);

    console.log(div.find('svg').html());
}
```

I call this function like this:

```
load_vector("#myDiv", "/path/to/vector/file.svg");
```

It successfully loads svg file to this div and now I have it as html in my page.

However I can't get contents of this svg file

```
console.log(div.find('svg').html());
```

This returns `undefined`.

Whad did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to wait until the load process is complete (it is async). Wrap your `console.log` inside a callback function. Something like:

```
div.load(vector_url, function() {
    console.log(div.find('svg').html());
});
```

Comment: Ooops. That wonderful world of async javascript. So many mysteries to discover. Thanks for answer).